# How to get the data using scrapy xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I tried to get the data of user but i cant able to get those things.

Url : http://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g34515-d3785272-Reviews-or220-Kings_Orlando-Orlando_Florida.html

I tried to get the first Reviewer Name Right now which is "LeLolita"

but I was getting user name from Q&A section that is "Kayal".

My shell script is

```
 sel.xpath('//div[@class="username mo"]/span/text()').extract()[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that site, the review information isn't coming together with the Request to the url you passed, it is instead on a request to a url like `http://www.tripadvisor.in/UserReviewController?someparams`.

I recommend you to check how requests work using chrome developer console, or firebug (on firefox), then you can see that visiting an url involves more than just making a request.

Another solution is to load all the site information using `selenium`, which works like a browser.

Comment: Okay can we do selenium without loading the browser because I am trying to run this on ubuntu server.

Comment: Yes you can look for some selenium examples